# Integrating CVS with SSMS 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, cvs, ssms-2005

Currently, I produce various .sql scripts (sprocs mainly) and have to copy them to another location where I had originally checked out a CVS project before I can add/update/remove the CVS repository accordingly (using TortoiseCVS).  It's tedious, so I've been tasked with investigating if SSMS could use CVS natively.

I've been googling after finding the Plug-in Selection in the Options > Source Control dialog, but everything seems to revolve around SourceSafe.  I'm not familiar with it - is this a Microsoft concurrent version tracking software?  Or could it be a wrapper to provide access to various software (CVS, Subversion, etc)?

What, if any, are the options here for making the link between SSMS and CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following CVS SCC providers:

- [Pushok's CVS SCC proxy](http://www.pushok.com/soft_cvs.php)
- [TamTam CVS SCC](http://www.brothersoft.com/tamtam-cvs-scc-76597.html)
- [Jalindi - Igloo](http://www.jalindi.com/igloo/)

I found them to be what I'd call beta at best, and decided that it wasn't worth pursuing when I could copy/paste files & use TortoiseCVS.

Comment: This is a real shame. I wish there was something a tad more approachable. Have you tried any in the intervening year?